# How can I deploy secret to multiple region from one cf stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I have below cf stack which is to deploy a secret on secret manager. The value of the secret is for IAM user secret key. Because IAM is global service, I can't deploy the same user to the other region. I added a `PRIMARY_REGION` condition to only deploy iam user from primary region.

```yaml
Conditions:
    PRIMARY_REGION: !Equals [ !Ref "AWS::Region", '${self:custom.primaryRegion}']

Resources:

  publisherUser:
    Condition: PRIMARY_REGION
    Type: AWS::IAM::User

  publisherKey:
    Condition: PRIMARY_REGION
    Type: AWS::IAM::AccessKey
    Properties:
      UserName: !Ref publisherUser

  publisherUserKey:
    Type: AWS::SecretsManager::Secret
    Properties:
      Name: user
      SecretString: !Ref publisherKey
```

The above template deploys a IAM user and saves the user key and secret in secret manager. When I deploy to a secondary region, I'd like to deploy the same secret in secrete manager but its value is from the global IAM user's key and secret.

But the issue is how I can deploy the user's key `AWS::SecretsManager::Secret` to secret manager in the secondary region? Is it possible I use one cf stack to deploy secret to multiple regions? If not, what is the best way to reference an existing value when go to the other region?

Comment: What is the full template? What exactly is happening if you deploy to other regions? Any errors?

Comment: Since IAM is global service, I can't deploy to another region with the same user name. It gives me resource already exist error. What I want is to deploy the secret manager in other region which has the same value from the primary region.

Comment: Your template is incomplete. What any iam user has to do with SSM secret manager? Your question lacks details.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I updated the question with more detailed info.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a custom resource. Otherwise you have to separate your templates to iam user creation and ssm.